# Merging Area Description Files for Project Tango

Tags: android, google-project-tango

May I append one ADF to another?

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/overview/area-learning#creating_and_saving_an_area_description):

> Depending on your settings, you can learn a new area or append to an existing ADF.

Similar to the way Tango is able to learn more about an area that has been localized, I would like Tango to learn more about an area that has been localized by appending an existing ADF that is related.  Tango would look for overlapping information that would relate the two files and translate the coordinates so the file being appended would use the coordinates of the main ADF.

> Because there are many reasons why an area may change in appearance, you might create multiple area description files for a single physical location under different conditions and select the correct one that will be most similar to the conditions the user will have during their session. Alternatively, you could append multiple area learning sessions onto the same ADF to capture visual descriptions of the environment from every position and angle, under every variation of lighting or environmental change within one file.

The scenario would allow smaller independent "learning" sessions that could contribute to an all encompassing ADF once an application realizes the two ADF are related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, The API doesn't provide any functions for merging two or more ADFs to one.
But you can append the new area's description to an existing ADF by 
Enable ADF : "Learning mode" and "Load ADF" mode

Check: https://developers.google.com/project-tango/overview/area-learning
on "Using Learning Mode and loaded Area Description Files part"

The last one is the condition I mentioned.
Also, in order to successfully append new area's description to an existing ADF, 
application must be localized to the existing ADF first. Then you can  start learning the new area. In the end don't forget to save the new ADF, which is saved as the same uuid.

Updated:
On the recent release. Append existing ADF will save as a new UUID. The new ADF area will cover your new area and the previous existing ADF.

Comment: Given the "understandable" limitations of the current API, this answer describes the procedure I'm using to satisfy my use case.  I'm picking a single point of origin and expanding the ADF after localization.

Comment: "You cannot save the area description until after you have localized against the loaded ADF. 
When you save, it will create a new file with a new UUID."
It seems you can only create a new file rather than append to the existing ADF.

Comment: "application must be localized to the existing ADF first" to do this, Tango should be started in LoadAdf Mode, and LearningMode would be false. Existing adf can't be saved with new area  when the tango is in LoadingAdf Mode

Answer (score 0):

You're outside the scope of what the system is currently capable of - you can create a new ADF or you can add additional information to an existing one, but the system doesn't have any facilities for merging smaller ADFs into a larger master ADF and there isn't enough documentation to hazard a hack