# Improving our Area Description .adf files

Tags: augmented-reality, google-project-tango

How do I append multiple area learning sessions onto the same ADF to capture visual descriptions of the environment from every position and angle?

Comment: Check I answer for pervious post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31111578/merging-area-description-files-for-project-tango/31145628#31145628

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there's no multiple ADF stitching pipeline available. However, you can enable learning mode along with loading an ADF. This will append the new "learned" area to the old ADF.

Also, please note that the learning only happens after the device is relocalized in the loaded ADF.